# my .json file is not accessible from d3.json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Here is my script to create a line chart. The json file is not accessible from the d3.json () command. I am new to d3.js in general and I am using Dimple.js for plotting charts picking data from back end. I have also listed the json content below from my file.

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#charts", 800, 600);

d3.json("C:/dev/reports/data1.json", function (jsonfile) {    

    // Create a new chart object based on this data and svg
    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);      

    myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Word");
    myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Awesomeness");
    myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
    myChart.draw();

});
```

---

JSON content:

```
[
    { "Word":"Hello", "Awesomeness":2000 },
    { "Word":"World", "Awesomeness":3000 }
]
```

Comment: You need to run a webserver to access local files. See [the wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) (under "Using").

Comment: hi Lars,in my application i have to pick data from back-end and display in line charts. What is the best approach to use? My FileWriter writes to my webapp/target/xyz/json folder whereas d3.json() reads from webapp/src/xyz/json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Chrome, it may prevent you from opening the file properly because of [cross domain security restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Try Firefox to see if that's the case (it will probably let you load the file correctly).

If that is the problem, you will want to install a local web server like [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (if you're running Windows) or follow instructions on the wiki page [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki).

It may help to use relative addressing to locate your `data1.json` file. if its in the same directory as your html file, just use;

`d3.json("data1.json", function (jsonfile) {`

Comment: this was good info that we need a running web server. it worked for me.Now I am trying to figure how to fit 4 charts in 1 page.

Comment: Well... You could do it [this way](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/07/arrange-more-than-one-d3js-graph-with.html) or [using bootstrap](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/07/a-more-complicated-bootstrap-layout.html) perhaps. Either way you could get a swag of similar info [here](https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read).